# Android sqllite. Can't delete row in table if String contains '+' character

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to delete row in table:

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(ctx);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String _number="+79261604030";
db.delete("calls", "number = " + _number, null);`
```

If I use just numbers, everything works fine, but if a string has a `+` sign, the row is not deleted. I think this is problem of special characters, but don't know how to change string.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: no errors, it just not delete row. and if sting have 19+ characters its not delete row too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use string concatenation to create a query. Use placeholders:

```
String[] args={"+79261604030"};
db.delete("calls", "number = ?", args);
```

In addition to being more secure, this handles all the stuff that you are not handling, such as quoting the string.

Comment: I took your advice and it worked, thank you very much!